# Create SFDX project vs code from repository?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, salesforce, repository

I'm trying to create a Salesforce SFDX project on Visual Studio Code using the git clone of the repository.
The issue is that in the aforementioned repository, there is only the "force-app" folder and nothing else.
In this case, how do I correctly download and create the project on Visual Studio Code using the "force-app" folder from the repository?

Can you tell me all the steps to follow correctly?
Thank you everyone

I have already tried with git clone.